# Inserting values with joined tables

Tags: php, database, join, insert, phpmyadmin

I have 3 tables and the **table1** has the names and **table2** has the items. My **table3** is table that joins **table1** and **table2**.

table1(info)

```
|  id  |  firstname  |  lastname   |
+------+-------------+-------------+
|  1   |  John       |  Davis      |
+------+-------------+-------------+
```

table2(items)

```
|  id  |  itemname   |
+------+-------------+
|  1   |  Shovel     |
+------+-------------+
|  2   |  Hammer     |
+------+-------------+
|  3   |  Wrench     |
```

table3(infoitems)

```
|  id  |  info_id  |  item_id  |
+------+-----------+-----------+
|  1   |     1     |     1     |
+------+-----------+-----------+
|  2   |     1     |     2     |
+------+-----------+-----------+
|  3   |     1     |     3     |
```

The problem is when I add new information, **table3** is still empty and can't display the values. What INSERT statement should I use to get the id from **table1** and **table2**?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you need to show your setup (table definitions) before anyone can answer.

Comment: check your `table1` and `table2`

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into login_table table1 tb
INNER JOIN table2 tb2 ON tb.some_id = tb2.id
(field1, field2, field3, field4) 
values
('value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4')
```